# Accessing ViewController UI inside "didInitiate" function after login

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, spotify

Mac OS Version: Mojave - 10.14.3

XCode Version: 10.1

Tested on both: ios 12.1 (iphone 8) & ios 10.3.3 (iphone 5c)

I managed to get the authentication to work, everything works I can get data from the user using their access token.

My only issue is trying to update the UI values on the current view controller after successful authentication, my UI Label `display_name` becomes nil after the app returns from the authentication phase in Spotify app or SFSafariViewController. Is there any way to update the `display_name` within didInitiate?

The weird part is that it works perfectly on the simulation: `DispatchQueue.main.async` works, but not on real devices

```swift
// In my ViewController.swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTSessionManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var display_name: UILabel!

    //protocol stubs for 'SPTSessionManagerDelegate'
    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didInitiate session: SPTSession)
    {
        print("success", session)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.display_name.text = "data from api" // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        }
    }
...
```

```swift
// In my AppDelegate.swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    lazy var rootViewController = ViewController()
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        rootViewController.sessionManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        print("application func")
        return true
    }
...
```

Comment: If you are getting an `unexpectedly found nil` then it's probably `display_name`. Check that you storyboard sets up `display_name` for all device interfaces.

Comment: Has `viewDidLoad` been called before your session delegate method? If not then it is likely the label has not even been initialized and so the implicit optional is still `nil`.